# How to you find out what group the current user belongs to via c++?

Tags: c++, c, linux

Using my c++ program how can I find out what group the current user running my program belongs to? So my program need to figure out a couple of things :

1. The current username of the user
2. The group the user belongs to

How can do the above 2 using c++ on a RedHat / Linux machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `getuid(2)` and `getgid(2)`. See `credentials(7)` for more information.

Use `getpwuid(3)` and `getgrgid(3)` for the names.

Comment: thanks for your answer... getgid returns the first group id, what happens if the user belongs to multiple groups? How can i find a list of all groups he belongs to?

Comment: You'll have to use `getgroups(2)` as given in the other answer.

Comment: Ok i figured it out....getgrnam() will return a structure with a member called gr_mem which is an array of all the usernames in the particular group.

Thanks.

Comment: To get the groups for any user (not just the calling one): use `getgrouplist`.

Answer (score 3):

You can find some of the information via [`getgid()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getgid.html) (real GID) and [`getegid()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getegid.html) (effective GID).  For the other auxilliary groups, you need to use [`getgroups()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getgroups.html).

In practice, the real and effective GID are normally the same, but it is the effective GID that is used when creating a file.  Usually, the group list returned by `getgroups()` includes the real group - though it is not clear that it actually has to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You use `getuid(2)` and `getgid(2)` to get the numeric user and group ids, then use `getpwuid(3)` and `getgrgid(3)` to look up those ids in the user/group databases and turn them into text names.